# Unmerge these two questions or fix the question

Tags: support

I'd like to know why [my answer to this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/boardgaming-online/1602#1602) was deleted?

It helps if a comment is left when an answer is deleted to at least give me a chance to edit my answer if it is incorrect.

Also the answer was upvoted so it was helpful to a certain number of people and it is a perfectly valid answer to [my original question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/what-board-games-have-good-quality-versions-available-for-play-online-for-free) which was merged with this question.

IMO the two questions probably should not have been merged although there was some overlap because my question was about online games and the other about resources for playing games with multiple players over the internet. Which I guess is why you decided my answer was irrelevant because the question has not been reworded to cover both questions in sufficient detail. The two questions have essentially been jammed together.

Deleting all the answers that were valid to my original question is poor form. Either the question should be reworded to support both lots of answers or they should be unmerged if they don't cover the same ground.

Comment: Pat L. added a comment to the answer [here](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/boardgaming-online/1602#1602) which I think addresses your question. Basically, for Community Wiki questions, it's considered a good idea to merge several answers into one. This is what happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the answer I gave directly on your [answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/boardgaming-online/1602#1602).

> Community Wiki questions in particular benefit from a different structure than regular questions. No further rep will be earned. Consolidating answers will give the community a better resource. When I added this answer to the highest upvoted one, I deleted it as I felt it had no additional value on its own.

I felt that I had left several [breadcrumbs](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) so that folks would know why I deleted a bunch of answers to that question.  My apologies, I had no intentions of angering you.

As to the merge (which I did not do myself), it appears quite valid.  Your question had a couple small additional points which would be awesome to add to the CW question.  I encourage you to incorporate them into the [question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/boardgaming-online) as it stands.

Comment: I can see where you're coming from and I can _now_ see that my answer has been consolidated into that top answer. I'd be interested to know why merging answers is the best option for CW? There's no anger, from my point of view I just want an easy readable format to my original question. I just feel the whole thing has been a bit poked and prodded and not entirely convinced that the final result is the best.

Comment: @xia - Would you agree that the [answer](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1594/boardgaming-online/1595#1595) is pretty readable as one main answer?  There isn't a lot of unneeded whitespace and your eye doesn't have to scan over the footers looking for the information needed (the games).  Once voting is taking out of the situation, I don't see the value in having one game per answer.

Comment: @xia - And yes, I've definitely poked and prodded it. If you have better ideas on formatting, please bring them up or try they out.  I have a few ideas myself.  The current format is a waypoint to my current perfect "ideal".  Time/energy will determine when I make further progress.  I was also hoping that others would contribute as well.

Comment: In the end, I also just want what is best for everyone. Not trying to be argumentative, just would like to know why this format is preferred for CW and not for other questions? You mentioned this is your current perfect ideal, is it also the way other SE sites likes to aggregate CW answers? Why is it better for this format with CW and not with regular questions? What's the difference? If it's not SE standard practice to do this for CW questions maybe I should post another meta question here to debate. Thanks for discussing!

Comment: @xia - no problem, I'm always willing to discuss.  Will have to reply more later.  Here are a couple CW questions from StackOverflow which is kind of the "goal" that I'm shooting for.  [List of freely available programming books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books/392926#392926), [What should a developer know before building a public web site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site/305381#305381).  Erg, can't find the truly awesome CW post I saw that partially inspired me